# Perl: Quick way to make a list of list references

Tags: perl, reference

I find myself doing this construct a lot:

```
my @listOfLists = ();
foreach (1..$count) {
  my @temporaryList = ();
  push @listOfLists, \@temporaryList;
}
```

Is there a less typing, one-liner way to do this?  Note that this doesn't work:

```
my @listOfLists = ([]) x $count;
```

It doesn't work because the individual items are all pointing to the reference to the same empty list.

Comment: `push(@listOfLists, []) for 1 .. $count;`

Comment: Why do you end up creating empty lists-of-lists? It seems ... odd. Perl does autovivify.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the anonymous array `[...]` in the loop:

```
my @listOfLists;
for (1 .. $count) {
    push @listOfLists, [];
}
```

for loop can be disguised as a map:

```
my @listOfLists = map [], 1 .. $count;
```

which is probably what you wanted to do with `x`.

Another thing is you often don't need it. Perl will autovivify the array for you when needed:

```
my @lol;
$lol[2][4] = [ 'a' .. 'z' ];
print $lol[2][4][3];  # d
```

Comment: Perl doesn't seem to autovivify if I don't specify a known index.  E.g.,   push(@{$listOfLists[$index]}, $item)  will return an error instead of autovivifying $listsOfLists[$index] as a new reference.

Comment: @onigame: Works for me: `perl -MData::Dumper -wE 'use strict; my @lol; my $idx = 12; push @{ $lol[$idx] }, [ "a" .. "f" ]; say Dumper \@lol'`.